# PostGis - ST_AsRaster returning raster smaller than reference raster

Tags: postgis, raster, raster-conversion

I am trying to convert a point geometry to a raster using a reference raster:

```
SELECT ST_AsRaster(my_points, ref_raster)
FROM my_table
```

This works fine except it is only returning a subset of the reference raster:

```
SELECT (ST_Count(my_rast))::numeric as pixel_count,
       (ST_Count(ref_rast))::numeric as ref_pixel_count
FROM (SELECT ST_AsRaster(my_points, ref_raster) as my_rast, ref_raster
      FROM my_table) AS my_inner_query
```

returns a pixel count of 2739 for my created raster and 3444 for my reference raster.

I have tried to understand the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsRaster.html) but it is not very clear to me. Does anyone know the correct way to create a raster from a geometry using a reference raster so that the created raster is the same dimensions?

Comment: Is the reference raster rectangular, at least in the pixels that have values?

Comment: The reference raster is not necessarily rectangular.

Comment: OK, perhaps I should rephrase that. Do the reference raster and the other raster definitely overlap everywhere.

Comment: The new raster (from points) should be entirely contained within the reference raster.